Looping over a cursor and extracting data in FoxPro
I was tasked in exporting all records from a database into Excel spreadsheets and name each one phoneNo.xls which is one or the fields returned by the select statement.
I did this but I am getting a single and really big file.
conn=SQLSTRINGCONNECT("Driver=SQL Server;Server=mcsql;Database=Patient;Trusted_connection=Yes")

RC=SQLEXEC(conn,"Select * from Patient.dbo.patients","Pat")
SELECT Pat
SCAN
Name = ALLTRIM(Pat.phoneNo) + ".xls"
COPY TO "C:\FoxPro\Name.xls" TYPE XLS
ENDSCAN

When I do
COPY TO "C:\FoxPro\" + Name.xls TYPE XLS
I get that Name is not an object.
When I remove the XLS
COPY TO "C:\FoxPro\" + Name TYPE XLS
I get a single file too with the phone of the first record.
Update: In order to comply with the helpful comments. Yes, I am trying to get count(*) files also I can do that to PDF.
Table Patients (Id, lName, fName, phoneNo, Status,...) like (1,John, Doe, 123456,...), (2,Jane, Jones, 456789,...)
I need files like 123456.xls and 456789.xls
I have also replaced COPY TO by
REPORT FORM C:\Reports\rep2.frx TO FILE "c:\FoxPro\" + Name and still got a single big PDF file.

What are you really trying to do? It is as if you are trying to create N Excel files with different names but same data (where N is the number of rows)?  Please instead of sharing code would you share some sample data and what you want to get as output? VFP is more widespread and taking help is not as hard as you think, provided you can explain your problem. (I am not the downvoter)

BTW, do not use TYPE XLS. It saves in very old Excel format (Excel 2.0?).

Your problem with this line is the extra ".xls" at the end:
COPY TO "C:\FoxPro\" + Name.xls TYPE XLS

You want just this because you already added ".xls" in construction the variable Name:
COPY TO "C:\FoxPro\" + Name 

But wait, presumably you just want this one record, not the whole table, so:
COPY TO "C:\FoxPro\" + Name NEXT 1

As the others said, never use TYPE XLS. That's Excel 2.0 form; use XL5 instead.

XL5 is also an old format. I would suggest using CopyFromRecordset using say VFP2Excel function. BTW, this code is not working for him Tamar. He shouldn't do COPY TO over and over for the same data set.

Helpful but as @CetinBasoz said, it does not answer my problem.

I failed to edit my copy and paste when I wrote that yesterday. Take a look at my answer now.
@Cetin, as I read the question, he's looping through a table and wants to save each record separately. So you're also right because he's saving the whole table. So I'll go edit my original answer again.

First, I can't say I really understood the question. On one hand you are saying XLS and on the other PDF. Though I wouldn't suggest using COPY TO ... TYPE XLS or XL5, assuming you would create 1 .XLS per row you got in Patients table:
conn=SQLSTRINGCONNECT("Driver=SQL Server;Server=mcsql;Database=Patient;Trusted_connection=Yes")

SQLEXEC(conn,"Select * from Patient.dbo.patients","Pat")
SELECT Pat
SCAN
    Name = ALLTRIM(Pat.phoneNo) + ".xls"
    COPY NEXT 1 TO ("C:\FoxPro\"+m.Name) TYPE XL5
    * Or
    * REPORT FORM C:\Reports\rep2.frx NEXT 1 TO FILE ("c:\FoxPro\" + Name)
ENDSCAN

Note that this is basically your code, with the main difference of the added scope clause (NEXT 1). In yours, it was creating one big file again and again containing all rows' data (COPY TO or REPORT FORM default "scope" is "ALL").
